# Unauthorized online banking personal identity compromised

Tags: california, banking, identity-theft

My father in law recently died. I have just found out that his girlfriend has been accessing a trustee account utilizing an old user ID and password. No funds were withdrawn, but the bank's cyber-security unit found that she was viewing statement activity on a daily basis for numerous months.

The bank has now suspended all online banking access to this account.

Question is, what is the legal position of father in-laws girlfriend in this.  Isn’t this a federal crime?

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clearer. If I've got anything wrong then please edit accordingly.

Comment: I don't see any reason why not. https://www.usa.gov/report-crime#item-35907

Comment: Did your father in law give her the credentials? How do you know it's actually "unauthorized: ?

Comment: She was helping him when he was alive, but when he passed away, the account closed and retitled as the family trust; banking protocol for some reason did not extend cancellation of old online access.  In essence she

Answer (score 1):

At the very least the girlfriend is in violation of the [Computer Fraud and Abuse Act](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1030) because she has accessed a computer without authorization and thereby obtained a financial record.

Comment: Is it clear the the authorization of the decedent (assuming it was given and not that the password wasn't on some "secret" Post-it) survive his death?

Comment: I can't see how it could. The account is a "trustee account". Presumably the decedent was a trustee, but even if he authorised his girlfriend during his life, his trusteeship and hence authorisation ended when he died. Also it was a bank computer, and the fine print in bank T&Cs says not to share your password, so it was unauthorised from that POV too.